# Caching Fluent NHibernate ISessionFactory

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We're building a mobile application, and we're evaluating NHibernate + Fluent for use with it. The problem is, the first time we create the ISessionFactory, it takes a full 2 minutes. even though the table structure is very simple (3 tables).

each call after that is extremely fast.

what i'd like to do is either cache the ISessionFactory between application restarts, or somehow speed up the creation of it in the first place.

Any ideas on if it's possible to cache? from all my reading, there's not much speeding it up.

Answer (score 4):

You can serialize and save the configuration and load that up the second time around to reduce the time it takes to create. Tho if you make changes you need to blow away the old config and serialize a new version, otherwise you will be loading up old configuration.

I can't remember the code to do this tho, will try dig up an example.

Edit: 
http://vimeo.com/16225792

In this video at about 24 minutes in Ayende discusses Configuration Serialization.

Comment: Good idea, but 2 minutes to parse config and build a session factory for 3 tables/entities seems ridiculously long. I think there is something else going on here, which should be sorted out first before complicating the app with config serialization.

Comment: Yes I agree, maybe he has his mappings in the same assembly as the rest of the application.

Comment: Here is some example http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2010/03/31/speeding-up-nhibernate-startup-time.aspx   But yes, it generally make sense only if you have hundreds of entities.

Comment: the 2 minutes only happens in the emulator and device, if we run it as a normal windows app, it takes milliseconds. but the serialization of the configuration is a good idea. we tried it and it's erroring on deserialization during startup, we're looking into why that part is breaking.

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work with fluent, or just regular XML-based nhibernate setups?

Comment: Quick google, found this which seems to suggest people have set it up. http://entron.wordpress.com/2010/01/06/optimizing-application-startup-time-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-unhaddins/

Comment: Turns out, it is not possible to serialize and cache ISessionFactory objects across AppDomains (and therefore, in between app instances). This is a known limitation, and it's even in the NHibernate source code comments. We're going to look into extending NHibernate to support it.

Comment: @bryan, you serialize the configuration, not the session factory. You still need to build the session factory for each appdomain, but you use the serialized configuration to build it. The configuration is all the XML/Mappings/Settings used to create the session factory. You shouldn't need to extend it.

Comment: yeah, we've done that, it cuts down the time by almost 30%, but the real time spent is in creating the session factory.

Answer (score 2):

Defining your ISessionFactory as a static variable (Shared for VB) and instantiating it only once upon application startup is how web apps get around this.
I realize this may pose a challenge for a mobile app with memory efficiency demands but depending on the mobile platform you're using the application lifetime may not be as short as one would fear...

```
    public class NHHelper {
        private static string _connectionString;
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

        private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory {
            get {
                if (_sessionFactory == null) {
                            _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ShowSql()
                                    .ConnectionString(p => p.Is(_connectionString)))
                                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(NHHelper))))
                                .BuildSessionFactory();
                }
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

// this is called once upon application startup...
        public static void WarmUpSessionFactory(string connectionString) {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
            var factory = SessionFactory;
        }
// this is what you call to get a session for normal usage
        public static ISession OpenSession() {
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
```

Comment: my issue is not the session factory being persisted within an app instance, it's between app instances that it becomes slow. therefore, this doesn't really help me. we're trying the caching instead.

Answer (score 0):

When building the Configuration and ISessionFactory, NHibernate is parsing configuration and mappings to build up its runtime data structures. (This is true of EF and LINQ-to-SQL too, though its hidden within the context.) There is not much that can be done to eliminate this cost, though 2 minutes seems awfully long. Timing this code:

```
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Startup time was " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
```

It's a demo project and only has a few classes and mappings, but it took ~850 ms without the debugger attached. With the debugger attached, it was around 2 seconds.

Have you tried profiling your app to see where it is spending the 2 minutes?

Comment: Yeah, we've done this which is how we discovered the time being so long for that particular item. and just to be clear, when we do this on a non-mobile emulator (like in a windows machine) it takes milliseconds. it's just that on the device (and the emulator it is so slow).

Comment: Ouch. I've never tried to run NHibernate on a mobile device. Probably a combination of slower processors, smaller memory size, and different run-time. (I'm assuming that you're running on the .NET Compact Framework.) I think Phill's suggestion above about serializing configuration is worth investigating.